# What happened to module filenames after minification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, module, node-modules

I'm trying to solve a problem with [this code](https://github.com/scaife-viewer/readhomer/blob/b393184/src/main.js#L11-L14):

```js
    import globalComponents from './global-components';
    // ...
    globalComponents.forEach((component) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
      Vue.component(component.__file.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], component);
    });
```

globalComponents is a directory containing an index.js which imports and re-exports two Vue.js component files. I didn't know you could do this, but I guess it's a way to do something like python module hierarchies.

Anyway, this code works fine in debug mode, but when built for release the app fails to load because the component objects don't have __file properties. What is this code doing and how can I make it work in a production build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `webpack` it's probably easier to use `require.context()`, which will save you some headache.

```
const files = require.context('./global-components', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
```

In this way you don't need to maintain an `index.js` file that just imports and exports all components for the purpose of this. Just create SFC's in that directory and off you go.

Comment: Thanks. That does appear to work, and not having to include boilerplate in an `index.js` is great!

Comment: Can you explain why the other method doesn't work? Why does `require.context` keep the filenames when import does not?

Comment: @RalphGiles Sure, you can see [it right here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/912ec9c14cf7b44b03fdfaabf7995b4c5f149350/lib/loader.js#L257). I suppose for the why my method works...because webpack creates a special context for you when you use regex or a glob pattern. Your way relies on `vue-loader`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!